# If I set java bin PATH Dockerfile Jar Command runs but tomcat doesn't

Tags: java, path, docker, tomcat

I'm creating a Docker file that FROM's the official TOMCAT 8 docker file and also seeks to use the jar command to extract content from a WAR file so I install openjdk-7-jdk.

If I don't set the PATH as follows the jar command does not work

> ENV PATH ${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin

If I do set PATH as above tomcat won't start.

How do I resolve this?

```
FROM tomcat:8.0

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get update --fix-missing --no-install-recommends && \
    apt-get install -y nano \
                     curl \
                     tree \
                     unzip \
                     openjdk-7-jdk --fix-missing --no-install-recommends

ENV PATH ${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

...

Thanks
Conteh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurred to me that I could use the full path to the jar command  **/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar** and remove the **ENV PATH ${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin** which resolved the issue.